# python / i want to solve TypeError: 'str' object is not callable

Tags: python

I've identified the total number of row and I've written a code to output one by one, and print values for each cell.
there's an error.

I want to fix this error. What should I do?
TypeError: 'str' object is not callable

```
import openpyxl
rb = openpyxl.load_workbook('backdata.xlsx')
ws = rb['Sheet1']
code_count = 2
row_count = ws.max_row
column_count = ws.max_column
print(row_count)
while code_count < row_count:
    code_count = code_count + 1
code = ws['C'(code_count)].value
print(code)
```

Comment: Well what is `'C'(code_count)` supposed to do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

change

`code = ws['C'(code_count)].value` to

```
code = ws['C' + str(code_count)].value
```